# remove space between character oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a column name 'phone' in table branch_dum. however the values in phone column like

'111 21 111111'

'11 1222 11222'

there are space between numbers. I would like to change my phone column values without any space like

'11121111111'

'11222211222'

what sql command I can write in oracle to replace my column values without any space between character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) function to change the phone numbers while selecting like

```
SELECT REPLACE(phone,' ','') "New Phone Number"
FROM branch_dum;
```

In case, you want to permanently change, then you can do the same in a `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE branch_dum SET phone = REPLACE(phone,' ','');
```

Comment: thank you, If I would like to keep my phone like '0208-124-1111' which command I can use.

Comment: @MohammadSifulIslamSumon, you should use same `replace()` function like     `replace(phone, ' ','-')`